# lcalc and the Analytic Rank of $y^2 = x^3 + 432764797 x^2 + 332896 x$

Tags: elliptic-curves, computer-algebra

I'm looking at elliptic curves associated with $a/(b+c) + b/(a+c) + c/(a+b) = N$. For the case $N=10400$, Michael Rubinstein's lcalc gives the analytic rank of the associated elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 432764797 x^2 + 332896 x$ to be 4, but it's actually 2. Is this a potential bug in lcalc, or something else? Magma's AnalyticRank() produces the correct value.

The command I'm issuing:

```
lcalc -e --a1=0 --a2=432764797 --a3=0 --a4=332896 --a6=0 -r --rank-verify=2
```

Output:

```
  ***   Warning: increasing stack size to 1000000000.
given rank 2 is different than computed analytic rank 4
analytic rank equals 4
```

Comment: Pari/GP's ellanalyticrank agrees with Magma on the rank and the leading term.

Comment: I might point out that *over*estimating the analytic rank is rather bizarre, as any computational glitch (either in a Frobenius trace $a_p$, or the weighting functions) is rather unlikely to randomly cause a nonzero number to suddenly become numerically zero...